# sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Despite many answers here I could not resolve my issue, may be I have not understand it correctly

here is how my `app.py` looks as:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify,session
from flask_cors import CORS
from dbconfig import employee_details,Emps_schema,Emp_schema,db

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'the random string'
CORS(app)

@app.route("/addemp", methods=["POST"])
def add_emp():
    empname = request.json['empname']
    email = request.json['email']
    department = request.json['department']

    new_emp = employee_details(empname, email, department,password='***')

    db.session.add(new_emp)
    db.session.commit()
    return Emp_schema.jsonify(new_emp)

@app.route("/emp/<empid>", methods=["PUT"])
def employee_update(empid):
    emp = employee_details.query.get(empid)
    empname = request.json['empname']
    department = request.json['department']

    emp.empname=empname
    emp.department=department

    db.session.commit()
    return Emp_schema.jsonify(emp)
```

If I try to close the session then the update[PUT] does not work(as per many answers ,after every commit there should be a session close )

and 
`dbconfig.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow



app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/empdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 30
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {"pool_size": 20}

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma=Marshmallow(app)

class employee_details(db.Model):
    empid = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    empname = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    department = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))




    def __init__(self,empname,email,department,password):

        self.empname=empname
        self.email=email
        self.department=department
        self.password=password

class EmpSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('empid','empname','department',,'email')

Emp_schema = EmpSchema()
Emps_schema = EmpSchema(many=True)

db.create_all()
```

How can i solve this error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30
```

Any modifications to my code to resolve this issue? please do suggest

Comment: I think the problem is that you are creating two apps, i.e. you have `app = Flask(__name__)` once in `app.py` and once in `dbconfig.py`. As `db` is configured with the wrong app, the teardown mechanisms that are usually triggered by Flask, aren't being called as the app that is tied to `db` isn't serving the requests.

Comment: (^+infi) Amazing sir.....Thanks a lot !!.........sorry for this noob question and least observation

Comment: @SuperShoot  Hey mate, I am confused here again, the same problem but this time I can't figure out on how....can you please look in to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338816/how-to-import-app-of-app-flask-name-to-other-files